# ActivityResultCallback not invoked for RequestMultiplePermissions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) to implement a new approach to request application permissions via Results API by `RequestMultiplePermissions` contract. Although the permission dialog is shown and permission result is propagated through the system to application preferences etc., my provided `ActivityResultCallback` is not notified at all.

Here are my source codes. I am aware I am not checking whether the user hasn't declined the permission already:

```kotlin
private fun checkPermissions() {
        val permissionList = arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )

        val notGrantedPermissions = permissionList.map {
            Pair(
                it, ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    applicationContext,
                    it
                )
            )
        }.filter {
            it.second != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
            .map { it.first }
            .toTypedArray()

        if (notGrantedPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            nextActivity()
        } else {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(notGrantedPermissions)
        }
    }

private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) { result ->
        info("> requestPermissionLauncher - ${result.values}")
        if (result.values.all { it }) {
            nextActivity()
        } else {
            longToast("All permissions are required for app to work correctly")
            checkPermissions()
        }
    }
```

Did I miss anything in the documentation?

- Library version: **androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha06**
- MinSdkVersion: **21**
- TargetSdkVersion: **29**

Answer (score 4):

I was up against this same issue tonight. I'm betting you're either extending AppCompatActivity or something similar. The issue with that is, when `super.onRequestPermissionsResult` is invoked, it falls to the FragmentActivity implementation which does not, itself, invoke the super method so the chain dies there. The quick solution is to extend ComponentActivity directly. However, if this is not feasible for your solution, you can override the method as follows:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    activityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(requestCode, Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent()
        .putExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, permissions)
        .putExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANT_RESULTS, grantResults))
}
```

The above is a direct port from the ComponentActivity method.

Comment: I am indeed extending AppCompatActivity. Overriding `onRequestPermissionResult` does solve the issue, but I have a feeling it's quite hacky solution. I looked up new Results API on Github (simply by searching for *ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions* - quite specific wording) and everyone is using AppCompatActivity. Algtough it cannot beconsidered as a source of truth, it either does not work for anyone of them, or the issue is different.

Comment: You'll hear no argument, regarding this as a hacky workaround. I'm sure this is just a temporary oversight as the library is still in alpha. With any luck, Google will get this wired into the AppCompatActivity either in the next few alphas or betas. In the interim though, it lets you move forward. All the best!

Comment: @ArchetypeAnarch You saved my day, thanks. For legacy reasons I'm not able to use latest version of `activity-ktx` and I was super surprised that `AppCompatActivity` is missing this override. Thanks for pointing out.